# Retrieving a table from database: "Bad request for field slot"

Tags: android, database

I have an database with 2 tables in it. In that in 1 table I have id   group 2 columns. Now I want is I have to retrieve the group data in the table.

My retrieving place:

```
db.open();
     for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
     {       
     if(i==1)
         group1=db.getspintitle(1);
     if(i==2)
         group2=db.getspintitle(2);
     if(i==3)
         group3=db.getspintitle(3);
     if(i==4)
         group4=db.getspintitle(4);
     if(i==5)
         group5=db.getspintitle(5);     
     }
```

My database code:

```
public String getspintitle(int rowId)throws SQLException
{   
    String sumtotal="";
    Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(
             "SELECT spin from spinner WHERE _id=rowId", null);  
//   sumtotal=cursor1.toString();   
//   cursor1.close();       
    for(int i=rowId;i<cursor1.getCount();i++)
    {
    if (cursor1 != null && cursor1.getCount() > 0)
    {          cursor1.moveToNext();         
    sumtotal= cursor1.getString(i);          
    cursor1.close();    
    }   
    }
    return sumtotal;        

//  String spin="SELECT spin from spinner WHERE _id='rowId' ";
//  return spin;
}
```

My logcat is:

```
07-18 14:12:01.890: E/CursorWindow(27405): Bad request for field slot 0,1. numRows = 6, numColumns = 1
07-18 14:12:01.898: D/AndroidRuntime(27405): Shutting down VM
07-18 14:12:01.898: W/dalvikvm(27405): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
07-18 14:12:01.962: E/AndroidRuntime(27405): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.budget1/com.budget1.Report}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 1 failed
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 1 failed
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:329)
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):    at com.budget1.DBadapter.getspintitle(DBadapter.java:208)
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):    at com.budget1.Report.onCreate(Report.java:65)
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
07-18 14:12:02.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):    ... 11 more
07-18 14:12:02.078: I/dalvikvm(27405): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
07-18 14:12:02.198: I/dalvikvm(27405): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-18 14:17:02.150: I/Process(27405): Sending signal. PID: 27405 SIG: 9
07-18 14:17:04.198: I/System.out(6293): subbu
```

Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT spin from spinner WHERE _id="+rowId, null);  
                                                                  ^^^^^^^
sumtotal= cursor1.getString(0);// zero instead of i
```

Comment: May I suggest to use parameter markers instead of adding strings. E.g. Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT spin from spinner WHERE _id=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(rowId) });

Comment: @Harald: thanks for suggestion but i am not changing his code, just solving his error...

Comment: by default the cursor alway point to first row but u must call cursor1.moveToFrist();

Comment: @gtumca-MAC: I know that you are changing his code but I was missing the suggestion to use parameter markers. Using + is a potential security hole.

Answer (score 1):

By the way look at

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("spin"))
```

This should be mush easier !

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method for clarification like the following:

```
Cursor cursor1 = db.query(true, "spinner", new String[]{"spin"}, "_id"+ "=" + rowId,null,null,null,null,null);
```